# I see repeated annoying pop-up messages claiming I have viruses. When I click "Remove Virus", I'm sent to the Google Play store. What should I do?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-3, antivirus, popup

this pops up whenever I lock my phone and unlock it. How do i fix this?

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Note 3. When i click on 'remove virus now' it redirects me to a page on google play store which shows a cleaner app.

Answer (score 4):

Visit a different site (and avoid this one in the future). That's a fake warning wanting to trick you into some download. Definitely do ***NOT*** hit that button labeled "Remove virus now" – if you do that, you'll have your device infected with some malware for sure. Don't get irritated by the Google logo, this is ***not*** a message from Google (they have other ways for "desinfection").

Never trust any such popup if it says your Android device has ***viruses*** – there are no viruses on Android (malware yes, but no viruses – there's a subtle difference). Second proof: a website cannot scan your device for malware, so how will it know?

One more pointer is the "countdown" in the second screenshot, which clearly identifies the message as [Scareware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scareware): No sincere and trustworthy software would issue an ultimatum to the user. The only intention here is forcing you to "switch off your brains in panic".

So either that website got infected – or it's even an intentional malicious site. Your device is fine.

Comment: The thing is I see this pop up even if I'm not in a web browser. Meaning when I unlock my phone, this automatically pops up.

Comment: a) the browser might still be running in background, and have the page open (go to *Settings › Apps,* open the Browser's detail page, force-stop it and "clean cache". Also consider to wipe its data from there to get rid of all open tabs). b) you might already have caught some [malware](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/malware/info) which is showing those popups. I think a) is more likely, as the report is associated to a web adress (your first screenshot).

Comment: I saw exactly the same screen! I just closed the browser without pressing anything (and killed it from the running apps screen) and never visited that page again. I also downloaded Avast and run a scan for viruses in my phone but nothing was found. It's been more than a month now and my device is fine. This happened though when I visited a specific page and not upon locking and unlocking my device

Answer (score 1):

**STEP 1:** Uninstall the malicious app from your Android phone
Android phone will get infected with viruses from a malicious app that is installed on the smartphones. In this first step, we will try to identify and uninstall any malicious app that might be installed on your Android phone.

To uninstall the malicious app from your Android device, go to the
**Settings menu, then click on Apps or Application manager** (this may differ depending on your device). If you cannot find the malicious app, we advise you to uninstall all the recently installed apps.

Touch the app you’d like to uninstall.This won’t start the app, but will open up the program’s App Info screen, then click on “Uninstall” button:

A confirmation dialog should be displayed for the malicious app, click on “OK” to remove the malicious app from your Android phone.

Reboot your Android phone

**Step 2:** Delete Junk files.
Now it's time to remove all junk files from your Android device (e.g. temporary Internet files, applications cache, etc.). This step is very important to maintain your Android device clean and safe. Some Android users have also reported that after clearing the browsing history and cache content, they managed to disinfect and remove the scam (fraud) Police lock screen message from their Android device.

Clear Internet history and cache on Android

**STEP 3:** Scan and protect your Android phone from viruses with Avast Free Mobile Security or MalwareBytes Anti-Malware
As you have seen cyber criminals have started targeting Android users for malware, and we do expect that in the months to come the number of infections will grow. In this final step, we will scan your Android phone for malware with Avast Free Mobile Security, and provide a real-time protection from future malware attacks.

You can download Avast Free Mobile Security from Google Play Store to scan virus (if any)